# Best Practice: Relative URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the best way/best practice to get a url relative to the current page?

```
string url = Request.ApplicationPath + "/MyFolder/MyFile.aspx";
```

or

```
string url = Page.ResolveURL("~/MyFolder/MyFile.aspx");
```

I have been using the previous method, but there was a question posted earlier today [Relative path from a root operator (”~”) address in code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464907/relative-path-from-a-root-operator-address-in-code-behind) that made me wonder if what i was doing was the best way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use

```
string url = Page.ResolveURL("~/MyFolder/MyFile.aspx");
```

But often times you can use just "~/MyFolder/MyFile.aspx" (HyperLink.NavigateUrl, Response.Redirect(), etc).

I don't think either way is better/worse, its just a preference. I think what's more important is that you consistently use the same method.

Comment: +1 for the consistency comment, I will be leaving this question open until tomorrow, to get other opinions but I had a feeling it was one of those "personal preference" type of questions. Unless someone can definitively show one is better than the other I will be selecting this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
string url = string.Format( "{0}/Folder/SubFolder/File.aspx", ResolveClientURL( "~" ) );
```

I find it to be the easiest and most reliable methd.